# How can I get the information that I already put in H2 Database to thymeleaf page?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

Client.java

```
package com.example.demo.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Client implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")  
    private java.lang.String nom;
    
    @Column(name = "adress")    
    private java.lang.String adresse;
    private String mail;
    private String telephone;
    
    
    public Client(String nom, String adresse) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.adresse = adresse;
    }
    public Client(String nom, String adresse,  String mail, String telephone) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.adresse = adresse;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }
    public Client() {};
}
```

ClientController.java

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import com.example.demo.entities.Client;
import com.example.demo.repository.ClientRepository;

@Controller
public class ClientController{
    @Autowired
    public ClientRepository cr;
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
        List <Client> list= cr.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("list",list);
        return "home";  
        
    }
        
}
```

ClientRepository.java

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.entities.Client;
@Repository 
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client,Long>{
    
}
```

main.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import com.example.demo.entities.Client;
import com.example.demo.repository.ClientRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Shop1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ApplicationContext crt=SpringApplication.run(Shop1Application.class, args);
        ClientRepository cr=crt.getBean(ClientRepository.class);
        Client c1=new Client("Bilel","Hammamet","myemailis","123456");
        Client c2=new Client("Wissal","Tunis","herrmail","1151");
        Client c3=new Client("Mohamed","nabeul","hisemail","444");
        Client c4=new Client("anas","Hammamet","his","55222");
        Client c5=new Client("mourad","tunis","fffff","44");
        cr.save(c1);
        cr.save(c2);
        cr.save(c3);
        cr.save(c4);
        cr.save(c5);
        
    
    }

}
```

home.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http//www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 > Liste des clients de la base </h1>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<th>ID</th><th>Nom</th><th>Adresse</th><th>Mail</th><th>telephone</th>
</tr>
<tr th:each="c:${list}">
<td th:text="${c.id}"></td>
<td th:text="${c.nom}"></td>
<td th:text="${c.adresse}"></td>
<td th:text="${c.mail}"></td>
<td th:text="${c.telephone}"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is an ss of my packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqWi7.png)

[This is an ss of error in localhost:8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBLps.png)

[This is h2 database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ttfM.png)

I tried to change in the home.html file but nothing happened I think the problem is in the home.html (Thymeleaf section). I think I have a problem calling the id, adresse, telephone from the repository which found in the h2 database to make them appear in a table in the thymeleaf page.

Comment: Check your logs for the full stack trace and add it (as code) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

One thing this cloud happen is some html tags aren't enclosed well. Like your  tag should be closed too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).